# Slackware won't ring my bell

Tags: terminal, kernel-modules

I want to ring bell in bash
I've set

```
lsmod |grep pcs
pcspkr                  1987  0 
xset b
```

and finally

```
echo -e \\a
```

But no ring.

Comment: What terminal/shell are you using?

Comment: I'm on xfce4 terminal,shell bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

```
modprobe pcspkr
```

and

```
echo -e "\a"
```

Works..but only on tty,not on pts.